# Change port for rabbitmqctl

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

You can specify a node for *rabbitmqctl*, but not a port. On Ubuntu, the only way to get *rabbitmqctl* via package is to install the full server. There are zero actionable Google search results regarding passing a port into *rabbitmqctl*.

Does that imply that *rabbitmqctl* is only meant to be run from the server?

Comment: What are you trying to do with *rabbitmqctl*? i.e. what's your end goal?

Comment: To use rabbitmqctl with an instance on another port, with an emphasis on managing an instance on another host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To administer a server on another host, you need to use the REST interface. There is no other way. The REST interface is excellent. It's exhaustive and perfectly RESTful. It requires the "management" plugin to be installed.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html

http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/rabbitmq_v3_3_5/priv/www/api/index.html

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe there is any way to specify a port with *rabbitmqctl*. It does appear it was meant to be run run from the server, similar to, say, the Apache web server's *apachectl*.

You can specify both for the host and port (via the `--host` and `--port` options) with the *rabbitmqadmin* tool, which allows a wide array of admin tasks to be accomplished. I use that tool, for example, to setup and teardown *vhosts*, *exchanges* and *queues* in a test environment via a *bash* script.

More info on [rabbitmqadmin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html).